# Char -Date field in sybase - Performance issue

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

i have a very big table and  requirement is to fetch the records based on char(10) field but actually it stores date .

it is taking plenty of time if i use 'between' in where condition. i have tried converting into date filed in where condition, still no luck.

i dont know why they store date in varchar, but i can't change anything now. Please help

Comment: please provide a sample query w/ the problematic `where` clause; also provide a few samples of the varchar(10) column (so we can see the format of the 'date' values); also, can you confirm that all rows have dates stored in the same format? also, is this column the leading column of an index?

Comment: index might help